# Asymetric and mesokurtic distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, symmetry

I need to find an example of an asymetric distribution with similar kurtosis to the normal distribution, and generate a sample in R.

I've already chosen the [4 density of Marron and Wand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23v8O.png) as an example of a symetric distribution with different kurtosis than the normal distribution, but I coudn't find the former.

Thank you!

Comment: [_A post_](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154951/non-normal-distributions-with-zero-skewness-and-zero-excess-kurtosis) by @Glen_b at the 'Cross-validated' site has several nice suggestions. Of these, the easiest to simulate would be the example based on uniform random variables. But I think there may be a mistake in the suggested value of $\alpha$ because I can't get my simulation of a million iterations to get convincingly close to the kurtosis of normal. [Also, I think he may mean a 50:50 random mix of the two uniforms, not $.5U_1+.5U_2$.]

Comment: From Wikipedia on 'kurtosis' :Mesokurtic
Distributions with zero excess kurtosis are called mesokurtic, or mesokurtotic. The most prominent example of a mesokurtic distribution is the normal distribution family, regardless of the values of its parameters. A few other well-known distributions can be mesokurtic, depending on parameter values: for example, the binomial distribution is mesokurtic for $p=1/2 \pm \sqrt{1/12}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the example from Wikipedia (mentioned in a Comment), here is a
simulation of a million observations of $Y = (X - E(X))/SD(X),$ where
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 10, p = .5+\sqrt{1/12}).$ By standardizing $X,$
we make the kurtosis of $Y$ be $E(Y^4) = 3,$ which matches the
kurtosis of a normal distribution.

Binomial distributions are easy to simulate. In R statistical
software the function `rbinom` samples from a binomial distribution
according to designated parameters. With a million iterations one can expect
two digits of accuracy.

```
set.seed(413)
m = 10^6;  n = 10;  p = .5 + sqrt(1/12)
x = (rbinom(m, n, p) - n*p)/sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
mean(x);  mean(x^4)
## -0.001070761    # aprx E(X) = 0
## 2.989588        # aprx E(X^4) = 3
```

I will leave it to you to verify analytically, perhaps using moment generating functions,
that Wikipedia's assertion about the kurtosis of this binomial distribution is precisely correct.